# signalr time lag on server, works perfectly on local

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, signalr

I am facing a unique problem with SignalR library. I am using this library for an online penny auction portal.

When i broadcast the bidder name and top bidder amount to all the connected users, i experience a time lag.

However this same code works excellent on local server. there is no time lag.

As per my understanding, at the moment there are just 100 auctions in the database and it should not be an issue for broadcasting latest bid amount and username to all the users and make sure the connected users are able to see the updated latest bidding amount and bidders name.

Also there are times i see this works on server, but when i try to change the tabs of my browser(i am using google chrome) and wait for some seconds, i experience this time lag.

```
        var context = new PetaPoco.Database("DataContext");
        context.Execute("EXEC udsp_TimerUpdate");

        IConnectionManager connectionManager = AspNetHost.DependencyResolver.Resolve<IConnectionManager>();
        dynamic clients = connectionManager.GetClients<Chat>();
        clients.gettime();

        var tmr = context.Query<CurrentBids>(";EXEC udsp_CurrentBidsEndBids;").ToList();
        if (tmr != null)
        {
            foreach (var t in tmr)
            {
                ////Put code here for Shopping Cart                                                               
                context.Execute(";EXEC udsp_AddToCart @0, @1", t.AuctionId, t.BidderName);
                clients.sold("00:00:00", Int32.Parse(t.AuctionId.ToString()), t.BidderName, t.BidAmount);
            }
        }
        var autbid = context.Query<CurrentBids>(";EXEC udsp_CurrentBidsAuto;").ToList();
        Random rand = new Random();
        foreach (var auct in autbid)
        {
            var splt = auct.Timer.Split(':');
            if (rand.Next(2, int.Parse(splt[2]) + 1) == int.Parse(splt[2]))
            {
                Chat.AutoBids(auct.AuctionId);
            }
        }
```

Comment: where do you see the lag between server and remote machine? in the server code? (the former being something you should expect especially if the machines are not on the same net which they usually are not when talking server-client)

Comment: side note. You should consider making rand a static readonly field. Re instantiating the object wil lower the randomness